# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' : org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, dialect, entitymanagerfactory

I'm migrating the spring boot parent version from 2.5.12 to **3.0.6** and I faced many issues that I could fix but I struggle with this one :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL82Dialect
    at com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.HibernateTypesContributor.contribute(HibernateTypesContributor.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.applyTypes(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:296)
```

my pom.xml (only dependencies affected):

```
<!-- versions -->
    <hibernate-core.version>6.2.5.Final</hibernate-core.version>
    <hibernate-types.version>2.16.3</hibernate-types.version>
    <postgresql.version>42.5.4</postgresql.version>
    <spring.boot.version>3.0.6</spring.boot.version>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

application properties :

```
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

java version : 17

Comment: is that issue resolved? If yes, please share the steps that you have followed!

Comment: issue still occurs for spring-boot 3.2.3 with java 17
can you help if it has resolved the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Take note that you are still using `hibernate-types52` which refers to previous major hibernate 5+. You should refer to the latest `hibernate-types60` dependency to fully migrate to hibernate 6+. As of time, you can use the following:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-60</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.1</version>
</dependency>
```